# Mark a point pdf in android

Tags: android, pdf, markers

I need to put a point on a pdf file. For example, I have a plant of a car and if I click on a damaged part, the system put a mark on local selected. The links shows a example that I want.

thanks for the reply

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdck1.png)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions - how is your question programming related? Secondly, what research have you done yourself? What exactly doesn't work, where are you stuck? Questions here are usually only as good as the question, if you don't spend much time doing research and asking a good detailed question, the chance you'll get a good answer is just about zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not enough detailed. You tag it with Android so it's seems to be for Android app.

You could manipulate PDF easily  with iText library.
Here tutorial to add image to PDF:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=59

Comment: @user3250732 Is it useful for you ?